Overwrite test run parameters for MSTEST in Yaml
I am trying to overwrite the test run parameters in the below yaml file but it is throwing this error:

Line: 35, Col: 1): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key

Can someone please advise how to fix and achieve it?
parameters:

  - name: environmentName

    default: Test

    values:

      - Dev

      - Test

  - name: variable1

    type: string

    default: 2024-06-04

    displayName: Date1

  - name: vriable2

    type: string

    default: 2024-07-01

    displayName:  Date2

trigger: none

pr: none

resources:

  repositories:

    - repository: auto

      type: git

      name: Autotesting/ Autotesting

 

stages:

  - template: PipelineTemplates\@auto

    parameters:

      techArea: Automation

      buildPipelineName: Automation

      testsType: Apis

      runSettings: remote

      environmentName: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}

      tagName: ${{ parameters.dockerImageTagName }

      runsettingsFileName: ${{ parameters.runsettingsFileName }}

      testFilter: ${{ parameters.testFilter }}

      

-  steps:

- task: VSTest@2

    inputs:

      overrideTestrunParameters: |

        - Date1 $( Date1) 

        - Date2 $( Date2)


- steps and - task seems to be out of place. At first there is key-values, than it changes to indexed array. Missing indentation?

I am still not able to get it to work. Can you please help?
